# How to extend the axis without changing the graph?

Tags: graphics

How to extend the y-axis without changing the graph that is set by the interval?

```
ParametricPlot[ { 0.06677273831511694*(1-E^(-8.145*t)), -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t },
 {t,0,2.6}, PlotRange->{{0,0.07},{0.,-3.0191292643518968`}},
 AspectRatio->1, ScalingFunctions->{None, "Reverse"} ]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you include the code to make that plot?  Also, do you mean to extend the y-axis but make the plot stop at 3?

Comment: ParametricPlot[
    {
    0.06677273831511694*(1-E^(-8.145*t)),
    -0.10917030600597447*(1-E^(-8.145*t))+1.2031921424186618*t
    },
    {t,0,2.6},
    PlotRange->{{0,0.07},{0.,-3.0191292643518968`}},
    AspectRatio->1,
    ScalingFunctions->{None, "Reverse"}
]

Comment: Is this `Show[Plot[0,{x,0,0.07},PlotRange->{{0,0.07},{0.,-5}}],
ParametricPlot[ ...the parametric plot you showeded... ] ]` what you are looking for?

Comment: use `PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., -5.}}`?

Comment: I think "include" meant edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., -5.}}` to make the vertical axis extend from 0 to 5 without affecting the range of the plotted line:

```
ParametricPlot[{0.06677273831511694*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)),
     -0.10917030600597447*(1 - E^(-8.145*t)) + 1.2031921424186618*t}, 
  {t, 0, 2.6}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {0., -5.}}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1, ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}]
```

[image]

Use `PlotRange -> {{0, 0.07}, {2., -5.}}` to get

[image]